# Find files older than FILE without including FILE

Tags: shell, find

I have a plan to use `find` to give me a list of files that are older than some FILE and then use `xargs` (or `-exec`) to move the files to somewhere else. Moving stuff is not a problem; `| xargs mv {} ~/trash` works fine.

Now, if I try to use `! -newer FILE`, then `FILE` is included in the list, which I do not want!

The functionality of that command argument does indeed make sense logically, though, because 'not newer' could very well be interpreted as "same or older", like here:

```
$ find . ! -newer Selection_008.png -exec ls -l {} \;
```

includes the file from the compare argument:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 and and 178058 2012-09-24 11:46 ./Selection_004.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 and and 16260 2012-09-21 11:25 ./Selection_003.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 and and 38329 2012-10-04 17:13 ./Selection_008.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 and and 177615 2012-09-24 11:53 ./Selection_005.png
```

(`ls -l` is only to show dates for illustrative purposes)

What I really need from `find` is an `-older` option, but none is listed in `find(1)`...

Of course, one could just pipe the output through `grep -v`, use `sed`, etc., or utilise an environment variable to reuse the filename (fx. for `grep -v`) so I can enjoy the DRY-principle, like

```
$ COMP=Selection_008.png find . ! -newer $COMP | grep -v $COMP | xargs ...
```

but it just seems to be a lot of writing for a oneliner and that is not what I am looking for.

Is there a shorter/simpler way than `find` or am I missing some option? I have checked the manpage, and searched Google and SO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
find . ! -newer $COMP ! -name $COMP
```

Comment: This is not bad, it saves a pipe. However, it also makes me type more stuff, incl. setting the env.var. which I would really like to avoid. Of course, in a script it would be fine :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not *exactly* `-older`, but `! -samefile` will exclude a specific file.

```
$ find . ! -newer Selection_008.png ! -samefile -exec ls -l {} \;
```

This will still catch a file exactly the same age of file, and because it is inode based,
there may be caveats dealing with links, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Find doesn't seem to support this. You could delegate the test to `test`:

```
find . -exec test "{}" -ot "$COMP" \; -print
```

Not very efficient as it runs a fork for each file.